# How to assing a vector to a matrix in eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen3

I want to assign a vector to a matrix of Dynamic size. As in the  following code:

```
    Eigen::Vector3f VectorCam; // Vector in camera frame
    Eigen::MatrixXf VectorsCam; // Matrix contains the vectors

    for (int i=0; i<=theta1.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "I'm In theta1.size for loop" << std::endl;    
        VectorCam  << sin(theta1[i]), sin(theta2[i]), cos(theta1[i])*cos(theta2[i]);
        std::cout << "theta1.size is:" << theta1.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << VectorCam << std::endl;
        VectorsCam.col(i) = VectorCam;      // Matrix of Camera Vectors
        std::cout << "Vectorscam" << VectorsCam << std::endl;
        
    }
```

in the terminal I'm getting this (below #### )! Knowing that the for loop is still in the first run and it is supposed to run at least 2 times before exiting ! I thimk the problem is in VectorsCam.col(i)

########
I'm In theta1.size for loop
theta1.size is:1
1
1
7.82347e-10
visual_servo_node: /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/Block.h:123: Eigen::Block<XprType, BlockRows, BlockCols, InnerPanel>::Block(XprType&, Eigen::Index) [with XprType = Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, -1>; int BlockRows = -1; int BlockCols = 1; bool InnerPanel = true; Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion `(i>=0) && ( ((BlockRows==1) && (BlockCols==XprType::ColsAtCompileTime) && i<xpr.rows()) ||((BlockRows==XprType::RowsAtCompileTime) && (BlockCols==1) && i<xpr.cols()))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `VectorsCam.col(i)` you must make sure, `VectorsCam` has at least `i+1` columns. And when assigning `VectorsCam.col(i) = VectorCam;` the number of rows in `VectorsCam` must match the number of rows in `VectorCam`.

Before the loop write

```
Eigen::MatrixXf VectorsCam(3, theta1.size()); // Matrix contains the vectors
```

(and I assume the loop was meant to be `for (int i=0; i<theta1.size(); i++)`)

Comment: I want to learn not just make the code work, so, why "Eigen::MatrixXf VectorsCam" alone still gives me the same error ?

Comment: Constructing a `MatrixXf` without arguments will create a 0x0 matrix. And you can't access columns (or any element) outside the size of a matrix (there is no "auto appending" happening).